# onclick div with glyphicon does not work when clicking icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, glyphicons

I got a menu that shows when the user click a "button", so i got the code below. It works when the user click in the div, but not when clicking on the icon in the span, can anybody explain me why? I have tried several combinations but never seem to be able to get it to work properly.

```
<style>
.dropbtn {
    z-index:4000;
    background-color: #888677;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color:#d6d1bd;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto
    }
</style>
<script>
function getMenu() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div id="myDropdown">
my menu
</div>

<div style="border:0px;z-index:1000;"  class="dropbtn" onclick="getMenu()" >
<a onclick="getMenu()">
<span class="fa fa-bars">test</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the code for the getMenu()-function? And you really shouldn't be using onclick-events...

Comment: If you can create a jsfiddle, that would be great. Where is the icon?

Comment: why have the onclick twice?

Comment: I tried to create a jsfiddle, but I couldnt get it to work. I used the menu example from http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the getMenu() function its hard to say. It seems odd that you have the onclick on both the div and the anchor. If the onclick is triggered from the div, then you shouldn't need the anchor at all i would have thought

If I was doing this myself I might try something like this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span id="menu_button_1" class="menu_button">
       <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu
    </span>
    <ul class="sub_menu" id="sub_menu1">
      <li class="sub_menu_item">
        <i class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu_button_1').click(function(){
    $('#sub_menu1').toggle('fast');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/trr0qnhp/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, yes that worked perfectly when I added your javascript instead. Changed it a little so it closes again. https://jsfiddle.net/g86zy99y/

Answer (score 0):

What You can try is to add the Font-Awesome glyph icon to your anchor using **[CSS pseudo-elements](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/)** in which You can place the **[escape](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes)** / **[variable](https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/)** which represents Your icon in the **[set](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/less/variables.less)**, which is being provided by **[Font-Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)**.

In your case, the code would look like something simmilar to this:

```
a {
    position: relative; /* Keeping the glyph-icon within the anchor */
}    

/* Pseudo element usage can be annotated with both : or :: (css2/css3 syntax) */
a::after {
    /* We need to add the font itself so our CSS can know where the icons are */
    font-family: ' Font Awesome font ';

    /* in this case, the content property is the actual icon we want to use */
    content: ' your escape/variable ';

    /* We get our icon out of the document flow, e.g. its positioning inside the anchor */
    position: absolute;

    /* additional styles for icon positioning */
}
```